# Git: resolve commit made with local date set to be in the future

Tags: git, github

Short story: I created a feature which logic depends on certain dates in the future, to test this logic I needed to change my local date and time... Once I was happy I did commit/PR which got merged. Sadly I forgot / wasn't aware about my local date affecting the git commit date... and got into such situation:

[image]

I only noticed it few days... And during these days there were a mass of other authors commits.

- What's the best approach to safely change the commits date?
- If I will leave the commit as it is, and someone will make commit to my changed files now (with correct date) - how will it work?

Cheers

Comment: The date and time is just for the commit meta data. It has no impact on the integrity of your repository. You can't change the date time without changing the history again. So my advice - Leave it as it.

Comment: Clear. Is it possible to ament that commit (date)? And what's worst possible outcome of this?

Comment: If this repository does not belong to you, you can't change public history. If it is yours, you can do it, but you will change public history which will lead to problems with other contributer. So actually you have to live with it.

Comment: clear... Thanks for your time ckruczek